# ERROR in Cannot find module './_Stack' @ multi main - webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use react-music (https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-music), after npm start i get this error message
ERROR in Cannot find module './_Stack'
 @ multi main
webpack: bundle is now VALID.

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './demo/index',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
      },
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style!css!postcss',
    }],
  },
};
```

Comment: Nothing we can do - post an issue on the `react-music` repo if this error is specific to that package.

Comment: Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: @taylorc93 does this webpack config might have an issue??